Asyncio CancelledError while using CatBoost
I am using CatBoost classifier model on large dataset (train data shape: (1526659, 389)). When I run the fit function on the train dataset I get asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError. But I cannot interpret the error message. I am using Kaggle environment.
This is the code I ran:
def kfold_catboost_sklearn(path):
    
    df_train=pd.read_parquet(path)
    
    
    dtype_counts = df_train.dtypes.value_counts()
    print("Value counts of data types:")
    print(dtype_counts)
    
    df_train.drop(df_train[df_train['target'].isnull()].index, inplace=True)
    
    df_train_object_columns = list(df_train.select_dtypes("object").columns)
    
   
    df_train[df_train_object_columns] = df_train[df_train_object_columns].astype('category')
    cat_cols = list(df_train.select_dtypes("category").columns)
    
    dtype_counts = df_train.dtypes.value_counts()

    print("Value counts of data types:")
    print(dtype_counts)

    # Extract category columns into a list   
    class VotingModelCatBoost(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
        def __init__(self, estimators, cat_cols):
            super().__init__()
            self.estimators = estimators
            self.cat_cols=cat_cols
            

        def fit(self, X, y=None):
            return self

        def predict(self, X):
            y_preds = [estimator.predict(X) for estimator in self.estimators]
            return np.mean(y_preds, axis=0)

        def predict_proba(self, X):

            
            dtype_counts = X.dtypes.value_counts()
            print("Value counts of data types:")
            print(dtype_counts)
            X_object_columns = list(X.select_dtypes("object").columns)
            X[X_object_columns] = X[X_object_columns].astype('category')
            dtype_counts = X.dtypes.value_counts()

            print("Value counts of data types:")
            print(dtype_counts)
# Extract category columns into a list
            X[self.cat_cols]=X[self.cat_cols].astype(str)
            X.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
            y_preds = [estimator.predict_proba(X) for estimator in self.estimators]

            return np.mean(y_preds, axis=0)  
    sample = pd.read_csv("/kaggle/input/home-credit-credit-risk-model-stability/sample_submission.csv")
    device='GPU'
    #n_samples=200000
    n_est=6000
    DRY_RUN = True if sample.shape[0] == 10 else False   
    if DRY_RUN:
        device='CPU'
        #df_train = df_train.iloc[:50000]
        n_samples=10000
        n_est=600
   
    dtype_counts = df_train.dtypes.value_counts()

    print("Value counts of data types:")
    print(dtype_counts)
    
    
    data_target=df_train['target']
    data_case_id=df_train['case_id']
    
    y = df_train["target"]
    weeks = df_train["WEEK_NUM"]
    df_train= df_train.drop(columns=["target", "case_id", "WEEK_NUM"])
    cv = StratifiedGroupKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=False)
    
    df_train[cat_cols] = df_train[cat_cols].astype(str)
 
    
    from catboost import CatBoostClassifier, Pool

    fitted_models_cat = []
   

    cv_scores_cat = []
   
    oof_preds = np.zeros(df_train.shape[0])

    print("credtype_322L summary")
    print(df_train['credtype_322L'].dtype)
    print(df_train['credtype_322L'].value_counts())

    for idx_train, idx_valid in cv.split(df_train, y, groups=weeks):#
        X_train, y_train = df_train.iloc[idx_train], y.iloc[idx_train]# 
        X_valid, y_valid = df_train.iloc[idx_valid], y.iloc[idx_valid]
        
        X_train.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
        X_valid.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
               
        train_pool = Pool(X_train, y_train,cat_features=cat_cols)
        val_pool = Pool(X_valid, y_valid,cat_features=cat_cols)
        clf = CatBoostClassifier(
        eval_metric='AUC',
        task_type=device,
        learning_rate=0.03,
        iterations=n_est)
        random_seed=3107
        clf.fit(train_pool, eval_set=val_pool,verbose=300)
        fitted_models_cat.append(clf)
        y_pred_valid = clf.predict_proba(X_valid)[:,1]
        oof_preds[idx_valid]=y_pred_valid
        auc_score = roc_auc_score(y_valid, y_pred_valid)
        cv_scores_cat.append(auc_score)
   
    print('Full AUC score %.6f' % roc_auc_score(data_target, oof_preds))
    print("CV AUC scores: ", cv_scores_cat)
    print("Maximum CV AUC score: ", max(cv_scores_cat))

    model = VotingModelCatBoost(fitted_models_cat, cat_cols)
    
    oof_df = pd.DataFrame({'preds': pd.Series(oof_preds), 'case_id': data_case_id})
    
    return model, oof_df

This is what I received from kaggle log:
8881.2s 465 0:  test: 0.5938166 best: 0.5938166 (0) total: 18.1s    remaining: 3h 57s
13393.1s    466 300:    test: 0.8314408 best: 0.8314408 (300)   total: 1h 15m 29s   remaining: 1h 14m 59s
17849.3s    467 599:    test: 0.8387940 best: 0.8387940 (599)   total: 2h 29m 45s   remaining: 0us
17849.3s    468 
17849.3s    469 bestTest = 0.8387940163
17849.3s    470 bestIteration = 599
17849.3s    471 
18065.5s    472 0:  test: 0.6430467 best: 0.6430467 (0) total: 16.6s    remaining: 2h 46m 5s
22597.0s    473 300:    test: 0.8326873 best: 0.8326873 (300)   total: 1h 15m 48s   remaining: 1h 15m 17s
27073.3s    474 599:    test: 0.8408039 best: 0.8408039 (599)   total: 2h 30m 24s   remaining: 0us
27073.3s    475 
27073.3s    476 bestTest = 0.8408038656
27073.3s    477 bestIteration = 599
27073.3s    478 
27286.8s    479 0:  test: 0.5662746 best: 0.5662746 (0) total: 14.4s    remaining: 2h 23m 36s
27383.6s    480 Traceback (most recent call last):
27383.6s    481   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 730, in _async_poll_for_reply
27383.6s    482     msg = await ensure_async(self.kc.shell_channel.get_msg(timeout=new_timeout))
27383.6s    483   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclient/util.py", line 96, in ensure_async
27383.6s    484     result = await obj
27383.6s    485   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_client/channels.py", line 310, in get_msg
27383.6s    486     ready = await self.socket.poll(timeout)
27383.6s    487 asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
27383.6s    488 
27383.6s    489 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
27383.6s    490 
27383.6s    491 Traceback (most recent call last):
27383.6s    492   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 949, in async_execute_cell
27383.6s    493     exec_reply = await self.task_poll_for_reply
27383.6s    494 asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
27383.6s    495 
27383.6s    496 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
27383.6s    497 
27383.6s    498 Traceback (most recent call last):
27383.6s    499   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
27383.6s    500   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/papermill/execute.py", line 119, in execute_notebook
27383.6s    501     nb = papermill_engines.execute_notebook_with_engine(
27383.6s    502   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/papermill/engines.py", line 48, in execute_notebook_with_engine
27383.6s    503     return self.get_engine(engine_name).execute_notebook(nb, kernel_name, **kwargs)
27383.6s    504   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/papermill/engines.py", line 365, in execute_notebook
27383.6s    505     cls.execute_managed_notebook(nb_man, kernel_name, log_output=log_output, **kwargs)
27383.6s    506   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/papermill/engines.py", line 434, in execute_managed_notebook
27383.6s    507     return PapermillNotebookClient(nb_man, **final_kwargs).execute()
27383.6s    508   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/papermill/clientwrap.py", line 45, in execute
27383.6s    509     self.papermill_execute_cells()
27383.6s    510   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/papermill/clientwrap.py", line 72, in papermill_execute_cells
27383.6s    511     self.execute_cell(cell, index)
27383.6s    512   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclient/util.py", line 84, in wrapped
27383.6s    513     return just_run(coro(*args, **kwargs))
27383.6s    514   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclient/util.py", line 62, in just_run
27383.6s    515     return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
27383.6s    516   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
27383.6s    517     return future.result()
27383.6s    518   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 953, in async_execute_cell
27383.6s    519     raise DeadKernelError("Kernel died")
27383.6s    520 nbclient.exceptions.DeadKernelError: Kernel died
27387.4s    521 /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2930: FutureWarning: --Exporter.preprocessors=["remove_papermill_header.RemovePapermillHeader"] for containers is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can pass `--Exporter.preprocessors item` ... multiple times to add items to a list.
27387.4s    522   warn(
27387.4s    523 [NbConvertApp] WARNING | Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `NbConvertApp`.
27387.5s    524 [NbConvertApp] Converting notebook __notebook__.ipynb to notebook
27387.9s    525 [NbConvertApp] Writing 153711 bytes to __notebook__.ipynb
27389.5s    526 /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:2930: FutureWarning: --Exporter.preprocessors=["nbconvert.preprocessors.ExtractOutputPreprocessor"] for containers is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can pass `--Exporter.preprocessors item` ... multiple times to add items to a list.
27389.5s    527   warn(
27389.5s    528 [NbConvertApp] WARNING | Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `NbConvertApp`.
27389.6s    529 [NbConvertApp] Converting notebook __notebook__.ipynb to html
27391.2s    530 [NbConvertApp] Support files will be in __results___files/
27391.2s    531 [NbConvertApp] Making directory __results___files
27391.2s    532 [NbConvertApp] Making directory __results___files
27391.2s    533 [NbConvertApp] Writing 531156 bytes to __results__.html

When I ran it as a dry run (debug run), that means DRY_RUN condition is met, the function is executed without problem. The dry run uses only 50k rows instead of 1.5m.
I cannot really interpret the error message. And I don't know how to fix my code. I have found about asyncio.CancelledError in python documentation, but that does not really tell me anything.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html
Why is the error happening? How should be the code changed to fix the error? Any suggestions are welcome.
